# Rank of matrix - Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra

I have this question:

> Assume that $A,B$ are $n \times n$ matrices.
>
> $BAB = 0$
>
> Assume that $A$ is an invertible matrix.
>
> Prove that $\rho(B) \leq \frac{n}{2}$

Here's my take:

If $A$ is an invertible matrix that means that $B = 0$.

(There is a theorem on our text book that proves that: "Let A be a reversible matrix and let B be a matrix for which $AB = 0$ then $B = 0$).

Thant means:

$0 \times A \times 0 = 0 \Longrightarrow 0 \times A = 0$.

We'll mark:
$A =\begin{pmatrix}
\mid &  & \mid\\
a_1 &  \dots & a_n\\
\mid &  & \mid
\end{pmatrix} \Longrightarrow A \times 0 = \begin{pmatrix}
\mid &  & \mid\\
0\times a_1 &  \dots & 0 \times a_n\\
\mid &  & \mid
\end{pmatrix} = 0$

From here, we'll get:

$A \times a_1 = 0$

$\vdots$

$A \times a_n = 0$

Which means:

${a_1,..., a_n} \subseteq P(B) \Longrightarrow span({a_1,..., a_n}) \subseteq P(B)$


From here:

$dim(span({a_1,..., a_n})) \leq dim(P(B)) = n- \rho(B) \Longrightarrow \rho(B) \leq n - \rho(B)$

$2 \rho(B) \leq n$

$\rho(B) \leq \frac{n}{2}$



**I have absolute no idea if I did this correctly and I'll be happy to know where are my mistakes.**

Thank you!

Comment: What are $P(A)$ and $\rho(A)$?

Comment: @Dave $P(A)$ it's the kernel, $\rho(A)$ is the matrix rank

Comment: You have correctly found that $B=0$ since $A$ is invertible, so this just automatically means that $\rho(B)=0$.

Comment: You asked for $\rho(B)$ in the question and found $\rho(A)$?

Comment: @gt6989b Oh I'm sorry, this is a typo. I'll correct it.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your help!

Comment: Beard, there is a new answer, not by me. I think he has it right, just switch the letters $A,B$   to get an interesting question.

Comment: @WillJagy I will, I'm sorry I made a mess, tried to translate it from my language and kind of messed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For simplicity, write $r$ for the rank of $B$ and $k$ for the nullity of $B$ ($k$ coming from kernel.) First note that, in general, if square matrices $C$ and $D$ have that $CD = 0$, then$$\DeclareMathOperator{\im}{Im}\DeclareMathOperator{\ker}{Ker} \im{D} \subseteq \ker{C}.$$ This is simply because for any vector $x$, $CDx = C(Dx) = 0$, so $Dx$ is in the kernel of $C$. This implies that $$\dim (\im D) \leq \dim (\ker C).$$

Applying this to our particular problem, we see that $$\dim(\im AB) \leq \dim(\ker B).$$ Since $A$ is invertible, it follows that $\dim(\im AB) = \dim(\im B) = r$. In other words, we have $$r = \dim(\im AB) \leq \dim(\ker B) = k.$$ By the rank-nullity theorem, $r + k = n$. So we conclude that $$2r = r+ r \leq r + k =n$$ as claimed.

Comment: yes, that must be the intent of the original problem. So   just switch the matrices $A,B$  to get a reasonable question.

Comment: Please note that I edited my question. It is not ABA = 0, but BAB = 0. The question in the the beginning of the post is exactly as its written in my notes.

Comment: @BeardGuy367 I’ve switched the roles of $A$ and $B$ to match your notation. The argument is the same.

Comment: @AlexG. Thank you so much, really, you took the time to answer and I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

$$ ABA = 0$$
$$ A^{-1}ABA A^{-1}  = A^{-1} A^{-1}  = 0$$
$$ IBI = 0$$
$$B=0$$

Comment: Oh, I see, I just over-complicated things. Thank you!

Comment: @BeardGuy367  possible, but just as likely that you don't have the intended conditions of the problem correct: perhaps typing errors in the source, or transcription errors.